# Probability of discrete event using machine learning in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to predict whether or not a customer, on any given day, will go to the store.

My data looks like this:

| frequency | recency | Event? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 0,2 | 4 | 0 |

Where frequency and recency describe the customer's recent behavior and 'Event?' is the binary target feature (1, the customer went to the store or 0, the customer did not go to the store.)

I want to use machine learning to output a probability (between 0 and 1) of an event occurring. I tried using Logistic Regression but it seems you need to input a probability in the training data for that to be meaningful. (The logistic regression probability outputs are ~0 or ~1).

Does anyone know how I can approach this, or what tools to use? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a Poisson process (like raindrops falling, or photon arrival in CCDs). If you use machine learning, you would be training a function to mimic the Poisson distribution (apart from the recency part :\ ). This is a start: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42465773/1021819

Comment: Since you have recency, this will also help you: https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-customer-lifetime-value-with-buy-til-you-die-probabilistic-models-in-python-f5cac78758d9 You don't need logistic regression but you could use it if you are determined to.

Comment: Could you post a full data file to test everything on? Otherwise any code is a bit hypothetical. Also consider datascience.stackexchange.com and stats.stackexchange.com - but you are not supposed to cross-post :\

Comment: Also Churn estimation: https://towardsdatascience.com/churn-prediction-with-machine-learning-c9124d932174